# Moderator display of repeated flags should show most recent first, not oldest

Tags: feature-request, moderator-abilities, flags

On the moderator display of flags on a Q, it may have something like this:

> Not an answer - UserName Timestamp, UserName

for repeated users flagging the same at various times. Using the Flag History option obviously gives us the ability to see in detail when flags were made, but can we change the default ordering to show the most recent flag first in that list, instead of the oldest?

Comment: Are there ever so many flags on a single post that you have trouble finding the newest one?

Comment: Are you talking about the Floating Collidinator, or the moderator dashboard?

Comment: @RobertHarvey On I suppose the floating collidinator, the one at the bottom of a page view. Not the view on the moderator dashboard.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek um, well, today, I had two NaA flags and could only see the timestamp of the one. This just seems like a way to generate one less pageview.

Comment: @jcolebrand Ok, I thought you were talking about on the flags page, where seeing the most recent flag involves moving your eyes very slightly. The box on the question doesn't show all the flags?

Comment: It does show all the flags, but for repeated flags (say pre-action and post-action) it comma separates the names. I haven't got any really fun flagsets tho with lots of flaggers, and I don't want to flag for the sake of testing atm (should be working no less)